# Creating a graph from research papers

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory, graph-neural-network

I am working on simple passion project involving graph analytics for research paper.
Basically, I want to create a graph structure connecting research papers and eventually would like to analyze how information is flowing through the nodes some thing similar to "Connected Papers" But as I am novice in graph analytics, I would like to get your advice on how to proceed forward.

When working with research papers, let say we have few informations just as:

```
{
'paperId':
'title':
'year published':
'abstract':
'authors':
'keywords';
...
}
```

I have have few nodes from 'id' with attributes listed above.
An example of unconnected nodes:
[image]

So, my questions are:

- How can I connect these nodes based on the attributes?
- If an article has an author who is also present in another node, the
  two nodes should be connected. How should we represent that?
- Also, for nodes, should I also be creating individual nodes using the attributes, for
  eg: should Authors have their individual nodes, similarly for date, institutions,
  keywords, so on..

It would be really helpful on to developing a strategy for building the network data structure before doing any analytics. I would like to request experts out there to help me on this side project.
I am currently using Python Networkx.

- What else should I be thinking in terms of tools?
  Currently I am only testing on ~30 articles, but would like to scale it up to 1000 articles, and even more if I can gather more articles.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do the papers have references to each other? How about PageRank algorithm? Or Wordcount and make papers nodes linked to "word" nodes, with "count" on edges for weights? Sure, institution + author could be their own nodes, linked to different papers.

Comment: Eventually, I would also like to have the citations included as well for sure. PageRank is fine, but I need to build the data structure first. I am struggling what entities to consider for nodes, and what entities to keep as attributes of nodes. Of course, I can create nodes for each of the entities, but then is it necessary?

Comment: You need to tell us first what you're trying to link together. Authors between papers is an obvious choice, as well as references, but if you want to link finer concepts, you actually need to parse the papers using NLP algorithms into common words / phrases, and that is mostly unrelated to graph building. Map your dataset into triplets like `(Author, Writes, Paper)` `(Institution,Published,Paper)` `(Keyword,MentionedBy,Paper)`, then that shows clear Vertex and Edge relations

Comment: I think the triplets ideas is helpful. The main information i am trying to link together are: paper, authors, year, institutions, country where author from, citations (maybe), keywords (in addition to keywords from papers themselves, will generate new entities with Named Entity Recognition).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I connect these nodes based on the attributes?

Based on the attributes you listed, I would not connect any vertices.

> If an article has an author who is also present in another node, the two nodes should be connected. How should we represent that?

Create a vertex for each author.  Add an edge from the author to each paper vertex that was authored.

> Authors have their individual nodes,

Yes.

> similarly for date, institutions, keywords, so on..

No.

> What else should I be thinking in terms of tools?

IMHO you do not want to use a graph for storing this information.  A relational database will be more suitable for your data.

Comment: If a graph is no good, then what good is a relational database without relations?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for your comment.  The OP's data has many relations, in particular between authors and their papers.

Comment: Right, so clarify "IMHO you do not want to use a graph for storing this information" ?

Comment: Thanks for wonderful discussion!
I do have relational database in the first place storing some of these metadata. I am planning to perform some anomaly detection on keywords to identify papers that are outliers, whether they are irrelevent text or they have some thing different. I might also use Vector Embeddings for that as well.

The main purpose of using graph is to discover new entities and related papers/authors etc.

And yes, it would be helpful why graph db will not be suitable for this purpose?

Comment: What are new entities and how are they discovered?